# VB.NET starting thread from a for loop "wrong" values passed in

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to start a couple of threads and can't explain what I'm seeing:

Mini version of the app:

```
Imports System.Threading

Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim theThread(3) As Thread

    For i = 0 To theThread.Length - 1

        theThread(i) = New Thread(AddressOf runme)
        theThread(i).Start(i)
        '^^^ version a above and b below
        'theThread(i) = New Thread(Sub() runme(i))
        'theThread(i).Start()

    Next

    Thread.Sleep(10000)

End Sub


Sub runme(i As Integer)
    Console.WriteLine("i= " & i & " - System Thread: " &Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
    Thread.Sleep(2000)

End Sub

End Module
```

When I run it, it works - I get output like:
i= 3 - System Thread: 13
i= 0 - System Thread: 10
i= 2 - System Thread: 12
i= 1 - System Thread: 11

which is what I expect. If I switch the New Thread code to version "b" (which is what I inherited), I get output like:
i= 2 - System Thread: 10
i= 2 - System Thread: 11
i= 3 - System Thread: 12
i= 4 - System Thread: 13

What is going on with i?

Comment: Your "b" example doesn't compile, for starters. The short answer is though, you are accessing a modified closure in the "b" example whereas in the "a" example you are passing it to the thread.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: @vcsjones: thank you for the explanation. However, it does compile and run in VS2010 just fine. The Sub() runme(i) is a copy and paste from the code I inherited and I hadn't seen threads started like that, always used the AddressOf.

Comment: Rolled back to version 1 because the edit removed the OP "version b" code that was commented out, making the question difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that in "version b" you are creating a new Sub and then running a nested Sub. Most likely the main thread has already progressed to the next iteration of i and now the thread is starting with i=2. This is why you get two threads both reporting i as 2. One way to test this would be to add a Sleep statement before the Next statement.

```
For i = 0 To theThread.Length - 1

    theThread(i) = New Thread(Sub() runme(i))
    theThread(i).Start()

    Thread.Sleep(250)

Next
```